# Extract a portion of the key in a dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I have two dictionaries:

- file1 dictionary:
  "abcd.0001" 1
- file2 dictionary:
  "abcd.0002" 1
  "defg.0001" 1

I want to find out whether a key exists containing "abcd". I cannot hard code "abcd". The following code provides an output "abcd.0001 is deleted in the new file", which is true, but I want the code to look for only a portion of the key and if it is there in both the files, it should not write an output.

Thanks!

```
   For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In file1dictionary
        If file2dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) Then
        Else
            objStreamWriter.WriteLine(kvp.Value.ToString() + " entries of " + kvp.Key + " DELETED in new PDI")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

This should make what you wish:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim file1dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer), file2dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    file1dictionary("abcd.0001") = 1
    file2dictionary("abcd.0002") = 1
    file2dictionary("defg.0001") = 1
    Dim correspondences As Integer
    For Each kvp1 As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In file1dictionary
        correspondences = file2dictionary.ToArray.Count(
            Function(kvp2) kvp2.Key.StartsWith(kvp1.Key.Substring(0, kvp1.Key.IndexOf("."c))))
        If correspondences > 0 Then
            'nothing done in this case
        Else
            MsgBox(kvp1.Value.ToString() + " entries of " + kvp1.Key + " DELETED in new PDI")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But I would code it this way, for short:

```
    For Each kvp In file1dictionary.Where(
            Function(kvp1) file2dictionary.ToArray.Any(
                Function(kvp2) kvp2.Key.StartsWith(kvp1.Key.Substring(0, kvp1.Key.IndexOf("."c)))))
        objStreamWriter.WriteLine(kvp.Value.ToString() + " entries Of " + kvp.Key + " DELETED In New PDI")
    Next
```

Comment: hi: this gives an output "abcd.0001" is deleted in file 2. I don't want that.

Comment: I don't want the code to print anything if abcd is contained in both the files.

Comment: For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In file1dictionary
            PNstart = kvp.Key.IndexOf("""")
            PNEnd = kvp.Key.IndexOf(".")
            'If file2dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) Then
            If file2dictionary.Any(Function(kvp2) kvp2.Key.StartsWith(kvp.Key.Substring(PNstart + 1, PNEnd - PNstart - 1))) Then
            Else
                objStreamWriter.WriteLine(kvp.Value.ToString() + " entries Of " + kvp.Key + " DELETED In New PDI")
            End If
        Next

Comment: @DineshM -  Sorry, I may have misunderstood it. But you said you can't hardcode "abcd", so where does "abcd" come from? I assumed it should be any of the strings formed by the first 4 letters of the keys in `file1dictionary`, since you perform an iteration on it. Can you explain it more accurately?

Comment: @DineshM, I edited the code in my post to do exactly the same as before, but in a more detailed, thorough manner. I tested it and it's shown no message, so I believe there is some mistranscription somewhere. Please note that I kept your fashion of using `If...Then...Else...End If` clause with no statements in the `If...then` portion, but only in `Else...End If` because, after all, is valid code that compiles all right. But it *is* odd. Why don't you test for the condition you want to raise the message?

Comment: @DineshM - another thing. Does the strings in your key collection start with the quote character (""""c), _besides_ the string delimiter quote?

Comment: Tried the concise code again and I get the same output. It prints "abcd.0001" is deleted in new file

Comment: I am reading a text file with part numbers which contains random alpha numeric numbers. that's why I said I cannot hard code the part number which is "abcd"